# unable to displaying category image in my creating module

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i want to display caregory images in my own module , so i create a module and frontend/templates/category-section.phtml , and this is the code , my problem is the source image is empty ,it returns null in my creating page ,all others properties like this works correctly

i uploaded the image in admin panel and when i click on the a tag it return the category pages with the image correctly but only in my displaying categories and images , the images arent displaying

[the images here arent displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8ded.png)

[if i click on any one, the url and image exist here but in new module arent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZeqN.jpg)

```
<?php echo $category->getName() ?>
```

```
<section class="section-holder">
    <div class="all-categories">
        <p class='category-text'>categories</p>
        <div class='categories-flex'>
            <?php
            $categoryHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
            $outputhelper   = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');


            foreach ($categoryHelper->getStoreCategories() as $category) :

            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
                    <div class='child-category'>
                        <div>
                            <img style="background-image: url('<?= $category->getImageUrl();  ?>');" alt="">
                        </div>

                        <p> <?php echo $category->getName() ?></p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `getStoreCategories` does not load the images of the categories. It only loads the attributes declared in `catalog_attributes.xml` files of the active modules.
You can try to add the image attribute to this list by creating this file inside your own module

`etc/catalog_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="image"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Clear the cache when you are done.